# $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM books WHERE tags LIKE '%$_GET[term]%' LIMIT 0,$_GET[results]");

Tags: mysql, arrays, search-engine

I'm trying to make a Like search engine, something simple for my site. Here is the code I'm using:

```
  $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM books WHERE tags LIKE '%$_GET[term]%' LIMIT 0,$_GET
  [results]");

while($ser = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    echo $ser['title']."<br />";


}
```

But when it searches, it will only look for a single Term within my tags. Any one have any good ideas on how to have it search through all my tags?

Comment: This is a poorly structured title. Please consider changing it so it is more meaningful. Since this is your first post, you can get away with it this time ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM books WHERE tags LIKE '%$_GET[term]%'");
```

Remove the limit from your query, you should get all the matching rows from your query.

Comment: the limit is a personal feature and has nothing to do with the over all function of the code. i have ran it both ways and cant seem to get the proper results.

Comment: WEll, if you are going to debug you poorly structured query you start off by removing the limit. Afterwards nothing should stop the query from working unless you do not have enough data. Try a simple query in phpmyadmin and see the responce.

Comment: @user2433591. In that case consider providing more information like example of excepted answers. Your question is vague. You are doing a where clause on tags and then asking to run through all tags, and you say the limit is intended, I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

i highly recommend not to use value directly from user first parse it, to protect yourself from SQL injections

try removing the limit and then check is it give same result?

Comment: Im aware of injection, im just trying to make this work ATM. thank you for your concern.

Comment: @Originative, while your first part of your post is certainly correct and informative, it is not answering the question directly. Kindly consider deleting and placing the post as a comment instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:-

```
$keywords =$_GET[term];
$keywords = explode('delimiter', $keyword);
$searchTermKeywords = array();
foreach ($keywords as $word) 
{

$searchTermKeywords[] = "tags LIKE '%$word%'";

}

$result= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM books WHERE ".implode(' AND ', $searchTermKeywords).");
```

Comment: this seemed to work but all its doing it revealing all of the entries with in the titles reguardless of the input.

Comment: This should work. Can you post a snapshot of the tags field. ?